# What is the right prototype of my select statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, count

I have three tables(customer, order, product)
 and I made a column in the product table that should have how many product is ordered by the customers in total. This means I want to know how many orders for each product submitted by customers.

I tried this statement in Oracle SQL Developer:

```
select count(customer_code) into product.numberOfOredrs
from order
where order.prodact_name = product.product_name;
```

But doesn't work.

Product table's columns:
product_name,
numberOfOredrs.

Order table's columns: 
Id_order,
customer_code.

Customer table's columns:
customer_code.

Comment: Why store this value?  You can calculate it so it is always up-to-date.

Comment: I would second @GordonLinoff.  One of the fundamentals of database design is to never store that which can be calculated.  If you you try to store this value, it's not a matter of "if" it were to become inaccurate, but 'how soon it _will_ become inaccurate'.

Answer (score 0):

You seems to want aggergation :

```
select customer_code, count(*) as no_of_product
from order o inner join
     product p
     on p.product_name = o.product_name
group by o.customer_code;
```

Answer (score 0):

The below query will give you the count of orders for each product for each customer.

```
SELECT C.Customer_code,p.product_name,COUNT(Id_Order) AS CountOfOrders
FROM Customer AS c
INNER JOIN Order AS o ON c.customer_code = o.customer_code
INNER JOIN Product AS p ON p.product_name = o.product_name
GROUP BY C.Customer_code,p.product_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the records in the `product` table then you can use as follows:

```
update product p
set p.numberOfOredrs = (select count(1) 
                          from order o 
                         where o.product_name = p.product_name)
```